# How we can pass the value following soap request in android?

Tags: android, web-services, soap

below soap request how we can pass the Destinationurl,Fields,FieldInformation values like type,Internalname

```
<soap:Body>
<CopyIntoItems xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/soap/">
  <SourceUrl>string</SourceUrl>
  <DestinationUrls>
    <string>string</string>
    <string>string</string>
  </DestinationUrls>
  <Fields>
    <FieldInformation Type="Invalid or Integer or Text or Note or DateTime or Counter       or Choice or Lookup or Boolean or Number or Currency or URL or Computed or Threading or Guid or MultiChoice or GridChoice or Calculated or File or Attachments or User or Recurrence or CrossProjectLink or ModStat or AllDayEvent or Error" DisplayName="string" InternalName="string" Id="guid" Value="string" />
    <FieldInformation Type="Invalid or Integer or Text or Note or DateTime or Counter or Choice or Lookup or Boolean or Number or Currency or URL or Computed or Threading or Guid or MultiChoice or GridChoice or Calculated or File or Attachments or User or Recurrence or CrossProjectLink or ModStat or AllDayEvent or Error" DisplayName="string" InternalName="string" Id="guid" Value="string" />
  </Fields>
  <Stream>base64Binary</Stream>
</CopyIntoItems>
</soap:Body>
```

Answer (score 0):

try this.

```
       URL url = new URL(Url);
       URLConnection connection = url.openConnection();
       HttpURLConnection httpConn = (HttpURLConnection) connection;
       String SOAPAction = "";
```

Convert your soap request as the string.

```
       byte[] b =s_body.getBytes();//make your soap request string as array byte.

       // Set the appropriate HTTP parameters.
       httpConn.setRequestProperty( "Content-Length", String.valueOf( b.length ) );
       httpConn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type","text/xml; charset=utf-8");
       httpConn.setRequestProperty("SOAPAction",SOAPAction);
       httpConn.setRequestMethod("POST");

       httpConn.setDoOutput(true);
       httpConn.setDoInput(true);


       // Everything's set up; send the XML that was read in to b.
      OutputStream o = httpConn.getOutputStream();
       o.write(b);
       o.close();
```